# Output empty text instead of unevaluated token (in JS Block)

Tags: blocks, tokens

I'm trying to output data through a block using JavaScript for [Intercom](http://www.intercom.io). Most tokens work fine, but if the source field for the token is blank, the token itself is returned instead of any value. Of course, I don't want to pass the unevaluated token. Any tips?